# How much data a 20 minutes Slack audio call may need?

Tags: audio, skype, slack

I have internet connection issues from time to time and was unable to join the previous 2 conference calls with the dev team. So, I was thinking to buy some data as backup plan monthly basis. Anyone knows what `kbps` Slack needs for the audio calls?

I find figures for the `Skype` and wondering if that would be any similar. As we have weekly calls, let's assume, I would like to cover 2 of them with the data plan (40+ minutes).

Will the 1.5 GB plan will cover both of them with some additional surfing outside? I have wifi in home and dont need the data

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to [this](https://get.slack.help/hc/en-us/articles/115003538426-Troubleshoot-Slack-Calls) link, slack requires 300k (bidirectional) This means 20 minutes of calling will require 300kbit/second for 20*60 seconds (and 8 bits per byte) which will consume about 45 megs of data per call, so 90 megs of data for 2 calls (assuming they used all the data - which they won't be)

In reality I expect they are using G711 - which is a standard codec for voice calls (because 100kbit is what is typically provisioned for these calls) - which means 64k of data in each direction + packet overhead, which means 80kbit each direction or 160kbit in total, so about 25 megabytes per call - 50 megabytes for 2.